# Joint distribution of negative binomial distribution

Tags: statistics

$X$ and $Y$ are independent.If $X$ and $Y$ follow geometric distribution with parameter $p=$probability of success ,I want to show $X+Y$ follows a negative binomial distribution using moment generating function.I tried to proceed as follows:
$$M_X(t)=M_Y(t)=\frac{pe^t}{1-(1-p)e^t}.$$
$$M_{X+Y}(t)=M_X(t)M_Y(t)=\frac{(pe^t)^2}{(1-(1-p)e^t)^2}.$$
Are my arguments complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Seems alright provided you can identify the mgf of the negative binomial distribution.
- You might like to specify the parameters for the negative binomial distribution.

Comment: Also remember that a **geometric distribution** is that for the count for *failures* before the first *success* in an indefinite sequence of independent Bernoulli trials with identical *success rate*, $p$, while a **negative binomial distribution** is that for the count of *successes* before the specified amount for *failures*, $r$, in an indefinite sequence of independent Bernoulli trials with identical *success rate*, $q$. $~$ Mind your "$p$"s and "$q$"s. $~$ The aim is to show $X+Y\sim\mathcal{N\!B}(2,1-p)$ if $X,Y\overset{iid}\sim\mathcal{Geo}_0(p)$.